# How to adjust touchpad scroll speed on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo, 22.10

I want to change the speed at which I scroll pages when I use the touch pad in Ubuntu 22.10. This problem is in all applications.

When I call the command `sudo xinput list`, my touch bar is not displayed. I assumed it was a driver problem but couldn't find a driver for my laptop's touchpad.

Version: Lenovo IdeaPad S340-15API

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:14              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:14              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I know that this question would asked a lot of times, but in my case, I don't have a touchpad at all in the list

Comment: What kernel are you using?

Comment: @David 5.19.0-38-generic

Comment: Did you found a solution?